# Import php to TextView

Tags: php, android, textview

I would like to put a php into a TextView, but I don't know how.
I can't set the TextView's text to the line of the php.
Here's my code.

```
 public class ItemMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_menu);

        final TextView gold=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Gold);
        Button back= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Back);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                input in=new input();
                in.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the code ,that gets the php. Should I change somthing in it?

```
public class input extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    public String HttpIn(String urls){
        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet in=new HttpGet(urls);
        try{
            HttpResponse response=client.execute(in);
            if(response!=null){
                String line="";
                InputStream input=response.getEntity().getContent();
                line=input.toString();
                return line;
            }else{
                return"Unable to get Data";
            }
        }catch(ClientProtocolException Cie){
            return "exception";
        }catch(IOException io){
            return "exception";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return HttpIn("http://worlddomination.pe.hu/login.php");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onPostExecute` method for updating textView:

Create Constructor in `input` for getting TextView :

```
TextView txtView;
public input(TextView txtView){
  this.txtView=txtView;
}
```

Override onPostExecute method in `input` class:

```
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       txtView.setText(result);
   }
```

And create object of `input` class by passing TextView object on Button click:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   input in=new input(gold);
   in.execute();
}
```

Comment: I have tried it and i get an "org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInpt Stream@41c287d0" text. Why am I get it?

Comment: @Lacko97: see following example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/GetTextfromHttpResponse.htm for reading text from InputStream

Comment: @Lacko97: Use `GetText` from example and use `line=GetText(input);`